# How to pass hidden values using form in jsp

Tags: html, forms, jsp, servlets

My code is as follows

```
<form method="post" action="Answer.jsp">
    <input type="submit" value="answer">
    <%String q_id=rs.getString("q_id"); %>
    <input type="hidden" value="<%out.print(q_id);%>"> 
</form>
```

I want to pass `q_id` to page `Answer.jsp` I got the value of q_id but I didn't understand how to pass (or using any different method) value?

Answer (score 3):

In your JSP form you'll need

```
<form method="post" action="Answer.jsp">
    <input type="hidden" name="q_id" value="<%= rs.getString("q_id") %>">
    <input type="submit" value="Answer">
</form>
```

Then you can receive `q_id` in your *Answer.jsp* as

```
<p>Question ID: <%= request.getParameter("q_id") %></p>
```

or, using JSP EL (recommended)

```
<p>Question ID: ${param.q_id}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

On page where you want to hide the value.

```
<form method="post" action="Answer.jsp">
    <input type="hidden" id="q_id" name="q_idName" value="someValue">
<input type="submit">   
</form>
```

Then on the `'Answer.jsp'` page you can get the value by calling the **`getParameter(String name)`** method of the implicit request object, as so:

```
<% String q_id = request.getParameter("q_idName"); %>
 Value :  <%=q_id %>
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: No I forgot to refresh page sorry ... But at Answer.jsp , on using   request.getParameter("q_id"); this will displaying null value