# how to pass retrieved mysql data into a hidden input tag inside a form

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I am trying to pass a value which was retrieved from database to a jsp page using a HTML form, but i think am failing to pass the result set value into the hidden input tag which sends to next page.i have included code related to the question.please help

inv.jsp: This is the code which retrieves data from data base and it  displays table table perfectly no problem there.

```
while(resultset.next()){ %>

<TR>    <% int gen=resultset.getInt(1); %>
<TD> <%= gen %></TD>
<TD> <form action="invgen.jsp" method="get"><input name="gen" type="hidden"><input value="Generate" type="submit"></form></TD>         
        </TR>
```

invgen.jsp: This part is failing to get the parameter passed by form.

```
String invno = request.getParameter("gen");
if(invno!=null){


String query="SELECT invno,invdate,mode,candidate,invamnt,sapid,DOJ,fctc,locn,band,skill,srvctax,sbc,total,gtotal from allinvoice where invno='"+invno+"'";
statement=conn.createStatement();
resultset=statement.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32921562/5710650

Comment: that works beautifully..thank you sir

Comment: welcome, please vote up as accepted answer. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass hidden values using form in jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920384/how-to-pass-hidden-values-using-form-in-jsp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change code like this.

```
<TD> 
<form action="invgen.jsp" method="get">
<input name="gen" type="hidden" value="<%=resultset.getInt(1)%>">
<input value="Generate" type="submit"></form>
</TD>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have to pass value in hidden field to get value in form action page as below.

```
<TR> 
   <% int gen=resultset.getInt(1); %>
   <TD> <%= gen %></TD>
   <TD>
      <form action="invgen.jsp" method="get">
       <input name="gen" type="hidden" value="hiddenvalue">
       <input value="Generate" type="submit">
      </form>
   </TD>         
</TR>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot type code but you should put the resultset in the request as a parameter.

In the next page you have access through request.getParameter("nameOfObject");

By the way: use a servlet to Query a Database an use the dispatcher to forward the result to the specific page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AJ93 solved my problem. just had to do a minor tweak inside for

```
<input name="gen" type="hidden" value="<%= resultset.getInt(1) %>">
```

it works perfectly.